# "Strikethough" on reputation in the user page, when hovering

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

When hovering the cursor over someone's reputation number in the user page, instead of an underline appearing below the number like with usual links, the line appears much higher and looks like a strike-through line:

> [image: segment of my profile page]
>
> (cursor doesn't appear in the screenshot, but it's there, hovering over the number)

Couldn't see it in other sites, but what I *have* noticed is that for some other sites that number looks bigger and nicer... maybe it's related.

Browser is Firefox 3.6.13 on Windows 7.

Comment: I do not see this. IE8 on XP.

Comment: No repro. Chrome Dev on Win7 (even with the pixelation mod turned off).

Comment: Repro on FF4 Beta 11. No repro on Chrome Dev.

Comment: i dont see it on FF 3.6.13 on windows XP.

Comment: I **can** reproduce it on Safari 5.0.3, Mac OS X.

Comment: cannot reproduce in Chrome 9 on Windows 7

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm on Win7 as well.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 10 (beta) on Windows 7.

Comment: Oddly enough, no repro on Chrome 9, Mac OS X.

Comment: I do not see this behavior on my FF 3.6.8 on Windows7.

Comment: I can't repro either.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 9 on Windows 7 with my zoom settings that screw up other parts of the CSS.

Comment: Can you still repro?

Comment: @fail yes (15 chars)